# Can't download song that shows as "purchased"

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-match, music.app

I recently purchased 6 songs to round out an album. I did this purchase from my phone (iPhone 6, iOS 8.4). Now, one of those six songs is missing from my phone, and I can't figure out how to re-download it.

Exhibit A shows the song as "purchased" in the iTunes Store app.
Exhibit B shows that the track, #13, is missing from the album.

How can I get this song back on my phone?

**Edit:** This song is also missing from iTunes on my mac, where all the other purchases have shown up due to iTunes Match. Where did it go?

#### Misc:

I haven't connected to my PC or knowingly altered the music on my phone.

IIRC, the song was downloaded, I definitely listened to it a couple times.

I also have made sure that songs not-available-offline will still show up by setting the option for "Show Music Available Offline" to off.

I am a subscriber to iTunes Match.

Under Settings->Music I have "iCloud Music Library" enabled

I do not have an Apple Music subscription nor free trial.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much Available storage do you have?  Settings > General > Usage

Comment: good Q, but 21 GB available